# how to pick up the file that subprocess.check_output generates?

Tags: python, file, subprocess, popen

I have problems in Python using the subprocess module. I want to execute 3 processes using the check_output function. Each process depends on the previous executed one as I try to explain in the next piece of code:

```
command_line_1 = '/home/user/fd/first_step.py' +" " + STATIC_FILE
args1 = shlex.split(command_line_1)
res1 = subprocess.check_output(args1)  
command_line_2 = '/home/user/fd/second_step.py <' + " " + **the output file of res1**
args2 = shlex.split(command_line_2)
res2 = subprocess.check_output(args2)
```

I read other questions and I wrote something like that. However, it does not work:

```
command_line_1 = '/home/user/fd/first_step.py' +" " + STATIC_FILE
args1 = shlex.split(command_line_1)
process1 = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
command_line_2 = '/home/user/fd/second_step.py <'
args2 = shlex.split(command_line_2)
process2 = subprocess.Popen(args2,stdin=process1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: It is quite unclear to me what the commands should do; you are splitting `shlex` (whatever that is) by the delimiter `'/home/user/fd/first_step.py' +" " + STATIC_FILE` (whatever `STATIC_FILE` may be). Then you use the result to run the command `subprocess.check_output(args1)`? Please explain what is what and what it should do.

Comment: I used shlex in order to split the command_line_1 variable, so that the check_output function can be use it as parameter. Firstly, I wrote            subprocess.check_output(['/home/user/fd/first_step.py', STATIC_FILE]) but then I changed it.